# Is there a way to fix a RollupError message when deploying a React project online?

Tags: reactjs

I recently made changes to a ReactJS project am working on, but when I try to roll the update to Vercel deployment, I'm getting a "**RollupError message**".

I attached two screenshots of the error below which also include the code to this message.

What could be the issue, and how do I resolve it?

[RollupError code Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD9jk.png)

[VS Code Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJY7R.png)

The error message mentioned the inability to resolve the components from the App.jsx. I tried renaming the components and importing them into the App.jsx.

While everything works fine on my local deployment, online deployment on Vercel keeps failing to show "RollupError"